# How can i make C program that scans user's input(text) and save it on a dynamic string

Tags: c, string, dynamic

I want to read input from user(text) using a C program and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i=0,x=0;
    char *c;
    c[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(1){
        c[i]=getc(stdin);
        if(c[i]=='\n')
            break;
        i++;
        realloc(c, i+1 );
    }
    c[i]='\0';
    //printf("\n%d",strlen(c));
    printf("\n\n%s",c);
return 0;
}
```

This program when it compiles there is 1 warning at `c[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));`:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

This program works succesfully but if i remove `x=0` from the code there is:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What should i change on this code so it can work without warnings or a useless random variable like `x=0` to work.

Thank you!

Comment: The compiler i use is GNU GCC Compiler and i use CodeBlocks and NetBeans to write code in C.

Comment: No need for `sizeof(char)`, it's 1 byte on any system. `malloc` shouldn't be casted. Get rid of the index on `c`. You're trying to give the first element a size of one char - this is all it can be anyway. Do `c = malloc(1)`, and *then* you can access `c[0]`.

Comment: I tried this but if i give a string with more that 34characters there is Segmentation fault (core dumped) After it prints

Comment: Maybe buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Dabo, adjust the assignment.

```
c = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Following are additional suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // Use size_t rather than int for index
    size_t i=0;
    char *c;
    c = malloc(1);
    if (c == NULL) return 1; // Out of memory  
    while(1){
        // To detect EOF condition, use type `int` for get() result
        int ch = getc(stdin);
        if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        c[i++] = ch;
        // Important, test & save new pointer 
        char *c2 = realloc(c, i+1 );
        if (c2 == NULL) return 1; // Out of memory  
        c = c2;
    }
    c[i] = '\0';
    // Use %zu when printing size_t variables
    printf("\n%zu",strlen(c));
    printf("\n\n%s",c);
    // Good practice to allocated free memory
    free(c);
   return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: fixed

Comment: This doesnt work either, after i give an input and press enter there is Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: Yes, forgot to  `i=0`, `c = c2`, and `printf("\n%zu",strlen(c));`

Comment: @user3504035  Code had a number of small issues, but the 2 killers were  `char *c; c[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` and `realloc(c, i+1 );` which would be better as `c = malloc(1);` and `c = realloc(c, i + 1);`.  Take your time to reflect on these and why they failed.

Comment: yes, i fixed this and now it works only on linux terminal and not on the IDE i use

Comment: @user3504035 I hope you are not simple copying the answers, compiling and testing without taking the time to understand why each change from your original code was needed.  Try the posted answer again in your IDE and Linux term.  Clear express the inputs, results and expectations should you still have issues.

Comment: I ve changed my code like yours and it works fine now, but i have 2 questions 1.Why you declare `int ch` when we need `char` input? 2.Why on my previous code without using temporary variables for `realloc()`and as buffer(`c2` and `ch`) like you do the user couldn't give input with more than 8 characters and without using `realloc()` like the example @aravind bharathy gave it works only on linux terminal correctly?

Comment: BTW: good your are reviewing carefully what happened.  1) Use `int ch`.  `getc()` and `fgetc()` returns 257 different values as an `int`, not a `char`.  The return values are 0 to 255, representing characters and `EOF`, which is _some_ negative number.  `EOF` represents the End-of-File-condition occurred or an IO error occurred.

Comment: 2) `realloc()` _returns_ the newly allocated pointer.  By doing `realloc(c, i+1 );` you are not changing the value of `c`.  You are ignoring the pointer to the newly allocated space. Further, the space that _was_ used by `c` is now potentially free'd.  So the second call may mess things up bad because you are freeing 2x, 3x 4x, times.  This _may_ not show up as a problem until a few cycles because the size originally allocated may have had extra space.  So the re-alloc just used the same block until things got substantially bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this

```
   c[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

with this

```
   c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and remove cast, you don't need it in `C`.

```
   c = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i=0;
    char *c=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(1){
        c[i]=getc(stdin);
        if(c[i]=='\n')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    c[i]='\0';
    printf("\n\n%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but if i give a string with more that 34characters there is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: I tried it. I just works fine for any number of characters(anyway there is a limit but not as small as 34). Try running the program from a linux shell(terminal). Don't run it from the IDE. Just try and see what happens.

Comment: You 're right, i tried this on a linux terminal and it works fine. Thank you, but why i can't run it from the CodeBlocks IDE, should i download a diffrent Compiler or something?

Comment: This has UB for any input other than `'\n'`.  There is only 1 `char` allocated, enough for the `'\0'`.